# JVM crash while executing google closure compilter ant task

Tags: java, ant, jvm, google-closure-compiler

I would like to use `google-closure-compiler` for javascript and css minification while building the project. `build.xml` is already prepared as per requirements.

Please find below `build.xml`:

```
<project name="ITV" default="run">

    <property name="webroot" value="webapp/scripts" />  
    <!--<target name="doMinification" />-->

    <tstamp>
        <format property="TODAY_MY" pattern="yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"  locale="en,UK" />
    </tstamp>

    <taskdef name="jscomp" classname="com.google.javascript.jscomp.ant.CompileTask" classpath="compiler.jar"/>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- ================================================================== -->

    <target name="run">
        <foreach target="doMinification" param="foreach.file">
            <path id="jsFileset">
                <fileset id="jsFiles" dir="${webroot}/">
                    <exclude name="**/Libraries/**" />                
                    <include name="**/*.js"/>                   
                </fileset>
            </path>
        </foreach>
    </target>

    <!-- Minify JS -->  
    <target name="doMinification">

        <!-- This gets the filename without the directory path. -->
        <basename property="jsFileName" file="${foreach.file}"/>

        <!-- Using Javascript functions to work out the paths -->
        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

            // get values
            fullPath = project.getProperty("foreach.file");
            fileOnly = project.getProperty("jsFileName");
            fileName = fileOnly.substr(0,fileOnly.lastIndexOf('.'));

            pathOnly = fullPath.substring(0, fullPath.indexOf(fileOnly));

            // store the result in a new property
            project.setProperty("directory",pathOnly);
            project.setProperty("fileName", fileName);

        ]]> </script>

        <!--<echo message="Compressing file ${jsFileName} in ${directory}" />
        <echo message="file only ${fileName}" />-->

        <jscomp compilationLevel="whitespace" warning="verbose" debug="true" languagein="ECMASCRIPT5" output="${directory}\${fileName}-min.js" forceRecompile="true">
            <externs dir="${webroot}/Libraries/Angular/">
                <file name="angular.min.js"/>
            </externs>
            <sources dir="${directory}">
                <file name="${jsFileName}"/>
            </sources>
        </jscomp>

    </target>

</project>
```

Now when I execute `ant` command, it starts the minification process as per the script. It works fine for few files and suddently it stops at point of time during the process. After waiting for some time, the below message is printed on command prompt.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d9a4351, pid=36500,
tid=37136
#
# JRE version: 6.0_75-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.75-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64
 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xd4351]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\hs_err_pid36500.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I tried multiple times with `ant` but everytime such message comes and `jvm` is getting crashed.

**What could be the reason and how do I resolve it ? Is there any issue with my build script ?**

Comment: *JRE version: 6.0_75-b13* - that's ancient. update.

Comment: @the8472- still same problem even after updating.